# R create .Renviron file

Tags: r, environment-variables

I know that there are already some explanations around about how to set variables in a .Renviron file. However, I couldn't find a solution to my question: How to create this file the first time. I don't want to specify the location for my installed packages, but want to insert a json file for API requests. 
So can I simply create a .txt file, name it .Renviron and write the code in the file?

This should be the content of the .Renviron file:

```
GL_AUTH = "auth/auth.json"
GAR_CLIENT_WEB_JSON = "test.json"
```

I also found this line of code:

```
Sys.setenv(GAR_CLIENT_WEB_JSON = "app/test.json")
```

Do I need this line of code to fill the .Renviron file instead of typing the code directly into the file?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: This is a good overview of the .renviron and .rprofile files, what they do, and how to modify them https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#r-startup